# variable changed in JS strangly

Tags: javascript, php

My my code. I have set a variable at the beginning of js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     var messageId;

     ...

$(window).load(function() {

    var relatedArticles = new Array();
    messageId = <?php echo $message_id ? $message_id : 0; ?>;

   ...
```

Then in other place, I only use variable messageId, not to change its value.

But sometimes the value of messageId has been changed, to 0 or undefined. not each time, but sometimes. And only happen one PC. I can not make it happen in my PC so can not debug the error.

I was very wandering if there is something wrong in my code, or something wrong is that specific PC or its browser, chrome.

Comment: the php code will not execute in the `.load` function. that only happens on the server side, where `.load` runs the client side.

Comment: @Daniel A. White. I missed something, this code is part of view of CI framework, this is a .php file, so the  php code will execute

Comment: @PhilipSong Does the problem persist if you initialize the variable before ``window.load``? Is the code that you posted located inside the ``head`` tag or inside the ``body`` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code in the first script tag to this:

```
var messageId = <?php echo $message_id ? $message_id : 0; ?>;
```

And remove the reference to `messageId` from the `window.onload` handler.

The PHP is executed at page generation time (before the browser ever sees the page) so there no reason to wait for `window.onload` to initialize your variable.  This will remove any uncertainty of timing for when that variable is initialized since it will be set from the moment the page is downloaded.

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with this. PHP is just drawing a page and sending that page to the browser.

Comment: @DaseinA - The OP is initializing a variable in `window.onload` which creates uncertainty for when the timing of the variable will be initialized.  This could very easily cause the variable to be seen as `undefined` if their Javascript tries to reference that variable before `window.onload` has fired.  Since the variable is being initialized by the PHP at page generation time, there is no reason for this uncertainty in `window.onload`.  Just initialize the variable right away and it will never be `undefined`.

Comment: PHP is just drawing the page. PHP doesn't care if there is a javascript code above that says ``$(window).load(function() {``. The undefined variable could be because it has not value before the window.onload event and/or because php is giving it a value of ``0`` sometimes, etc.

Comment: @DaseinA - can you at least agree that it's wrong and unnecessary to initialize `messageId` with the type of value the OP is using in `window.onload`?  And that putting the initialization in `window.onload` creates a timing opportunity for code to access that variable before it has been initialized. That's the point of this answer.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. But I still do not understand that why this error only happen sometimes, not very time.

Comment: @PhilipSong - because the timing of when the `window.onload` event occurs varies depending upon browser, network conditions, what is previously in the browser cache, etc...  It varies a lot from one computer to the next.  If you just initialize the variable right away, you won't have that variability.  I can't say if that is the only thing causing your problem, but it IS one possible source of a problem like you describe so it should be fixed.

Comment: @jfriend00 it depends. I might need a variable properly set just when the whole page was rendered. The location is relative of your intentions. There is not general rule about that.

Comment: @DaseinA - The PHP generated value is a constant for any given page.  It is set by the PHP at page generation time and from the moment the browser sees the web page, the value is always the same.  So, there's ZERO reason **in this case** to wait until `window.onload` to initialize it.  Plus, the entire problem described by the OP is that some clients are seeing an uninitialized variable in some (hard to reproduce) circumstances.  Having a delayed initialization in window.onload is both unnecessary in this case and could easily be the cause of the problem the OP describes.

Comment: @jfriend00 AGAIN: PHP has nothing to do with this. The explanation is on JS. In javascript, if you want the variable before the window.load event, set the variable before window.load event, it doesn't matter if you are using dynamic server script. That's all I was saying. The PHP explanation is confuse. Set the variable from the beggining, before window.onload. in javascript. Regards.

Comment: @DaseinA - the OP likely has a timing issue in their code.  There is no reason to be delaying the initialization of the `mesasgeId` variable in `window.onload` which may be the cause of their timing issue.  And, the reason we know that there is no reason to be delaying the initialization of that variable is that the value that they are initializing it to is known at page generation time before the browser has even seen the page (that's the relevant PHP part) so thus there can be no reason to delay the initialization.  I'm suggesting how the OP can remove a potential timing problem.

Comment: @PhilipSong Does the problem persist if you initialize the variable before window.load? Is the code that you posted located inside the ``head`` tag or inside the ``body`` tag?

Comment: @jfriend00 I can't be doing this all day long and I'm pretty sure you neither. Peace bro. And have a good day.

Comment: @DaseinA, This js code is in the body tag. Is there some different for in `head` tag or `body` tag?  I does not know if the solution of jfriend00 fixed the problem, since I need my colleague to give a response. But I think the solution of jfriend00 should be the right. I set the line ` var messageId = 0;` at the beginning of js code, it report to me the error of `messageId` is 0. Last week, I changed to `var messageId;`. Today, it reported to me undefined of `messageId`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add quotes to var like this:

```
messageId = "<?php echo $message_id ? $message_id : 0; ?>";
```

and later try to parse it if needed to be int ..

```
messageId = parseInt( messageId ) ;
```

but only if Id's are int for sure,, not something like : AK47 or like..

hth